# Why my requests session expire?

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests, persistence

I am using requests 2.12.1 library in Python 2.7 and Django 1.10 for consume web services. When I use a session for save cookies and use persistence, and pass 10 seconds ~ without use any web service, my view regenerates the object requests.Session()...

This makes web service doesn't serve me, because my view has changed the cookies.

This is my Views.py:

```
client_session = requests.Session()

@watch_login
def loginUI(request):
        response        =   client_session.post(URL_API+'login/', data={'username': username, 'password': password,})
        json_login      =   response.json()

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def home(request):
  response_statistics = client_session.get(URL_API+'statistics/')
  log('ClientSession: '+str(client_session))

  try:
      json_statistics     =   response_statistics.json()
  except ValueError:
      log('ExcepcionClientSession: '+str(client_session))

      return logoutUI(request)

  return render(request, "UI/home.html", {
      'phone_calls'           :   json_statistics['phone_calls'],
      'mobile_calls'          :   json_statistics['mobile_calls'],
      'other_calls'           :   json_statistics['other_calls'],
      'top_called_phones'     :   json_statistics['top_called_phones'],
      'call_ranges_week'      :   json_statistics['call_ranges_week'],
      'call_ranges_weekend'   :   json_statistics['call_ranges_weekend'],
      'access_data'           :   accessData(request.user.username),
  })

  def userFeaturesFormInit(clientRequest):
    log('FeaturesClientSession: '+str(client_session))
    response = client_session.get(URL_API+'features/')

    try:
        json_features   =   response.json()
    except ValueError as e:
        log('ExcepcionFeaturesClientSession: '+str(client_session))
        raise e
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using django ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using django.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it specifying cookies manually, and saving it in the request.

```
client_session = requests.Session()
response = client_session.post(URL_API+'login/', {'username': username, 'password': password,})
request.session['cookiecsrf']      =   client_session.cookies['csrftoken']
request.session['cookiesession']   =   client_session.cookies['sessionid']
```

And sending it in the gets/posts:

```
cookies = {'csrftoken' : request.session['cookiecsrf'], 'sessionid': request.session['cookiesession']}
response = requests.get(URL, cookies=cookies)
```